# SVN How can i add 2 new files from one branch to another branch?

Tags: eclipse, svn, rabbitvcs

I have a branch which have 2 new files .I want to merge those files to another branch - NOT trunk?

Is it actually merge ?- because the new files are not in destination branch

I tried to do a check out of branchB and try to merge the files from BranchA

but gives me some error .What is the proper way to do it?

One more question - If i check out an existing branch , is it creating a new branch or 
just its copy in my local system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Checkout the branch that you want to add the files and add them manually then commit. trunk or any other folder is treated the same. It's just a folder.

Checking out will copy files from server into your local system. depending on destination in your system it will copy new files and/or will give you warning if there are modified files in the destination.

Comment: man... that was actually simple. i was doing some other complicated things.! I check out his branch. added the new files .commit it. Simple. There are no difficult thing in this world. You know it or you dont know . Thats it. Thanks.

Comment: but if the file is already there . manual compare and merge will be better or shall i go after svn merge?

Comment: if you have modified your local copy and someone has committed a new version to the svn repository then try to "svn update". svn will try to merge the changes on your local copy. It will tell you if it isn't successful(if it has conflict). if it's not successful, you have to do the manual compare and merge. Always do the merge on your local copy before committing.

Comment: The problem with this approach is it will cause a tree conflict when you merge both branches back into trunk.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many files checked-in in branch A with revision number Ar, Now if you want to merge this revision Ar from Branch A to Branch B,

Simply checkout the branch B, inside src, right click -> SVN Tortoise -> Merge

Select the cross branch merge radio button (first one) , and give in the Branch A src URL, also give the revision number you want to merge into Branch B from Branch A.

Click the Test Merge button, to mock the merge

If all goes well, hit the actual merge button